# Page scrolls to top also fixed navbar when external link opens Tab

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a link in my navigation that opens a specific tab on a page, the link works fine, but the page opens so the beginning of the content is hidden by the fixed navbar. Can anybody help me, I am new to bootstrap and not very good in java:

```
var gotoHashTab = function (customHash) {
    var hash = customHash || location.hash;
    var hashPieces = hash.split('?'),
        activeTab = $('[href=' + hashPieces[0] + ']');
    activeTab && activeTab.tab('show');
}

// onready go to the tab requested in the page hash
gotoHashTab();

// when the nav item is selected update the page hash
$('.nav a').on('shown', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})

// when a link within a tab is clicked, go to the tab requested
$('.tab-pane a').click(function (event) {
    if (event.target.hash) {
        gotoHashTab(event.target.hash);
    }
});
```

or is there a better script to use external links to open a specific tab on different page for bootstrap 3 ?

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you want, and how it works, but can't you set a margin-top in that tab to previne that ?

Comment: when I open the tab on the page itself the margin is fine, just when I use the link to open the tab the navbar hides the beginning of the tab. I changed the java to a more simple one: `$(function () { var a = $('[href=' + location.hash + ']'); a && a.tab('show'); });` but stil the same problem

Comment: Add top padding on the body of the height of the navbar, if the fixed position is added on scroll, see my answer below. body {padding-top:50px}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the class .anchor on the anchor (the target).

If the navbar is only fixed on certain sizes, then where the ???px is, put the min-width of that breakpoint (992px for md and up, 1200px for large and up, and 768px for small and up).

```
@media (min-width: ???px) {
  .anchor {
    padding-top: 60px;
    margin-top: -60px;
  }
}
```

If fixed at all screen sizes:

```
 .anchor {
    padding-top: 60px;
    margin-top: -60px;
  }
```

**Assumes height of 50px on the navbar.** Also, this may *not* be necessary if your body top padding has the padding of the height of navbar as per the getbootstrap.com examples.

Comment: I got a body top paddding and the tab looks fine when I open the tab itself, but I got a problem when I open the tab on the page with a link from the navbar (the navbar hides the beginning of the tab

Comment: Then stick the class .anchor on that target and add the css after all other css. I had the same issue.

Comment: This works perfect, for some strange reason I had to set the padding and margin to 1200px, but seams to work on all devices. Thank you so much, I tried to fix this the hole day

Comment: Very odd, do you have 100% height on your html? Send me the link, curious.

Comment: staging.koller.rfcsystems.com/deu/Kaufen_/mitbieten.asp

Comment: And what link/menu item is the anchor?

Comment: I see it's not 1200px, it's 200px, well yes your navbar is not the standard 50px, so you would need to account for your particular navbar height and some extra padding/margin so that it doesn't look odd.

Comment: (Auktionen/Philosophie) Yes i changed this to 200 px and it worked as well. Is there a good alternative to use tabs in bootstrap ? I used countrytabs before and that was much simpler

Comment: Depends on what you want the tabs to do. Do want them responsive? Do they convert into accordion at smaller sizes? If you don't care about responsive, then http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/ are good. Also Bootstrap's tabs are nice, but also not responsive (yet). There's also http://webtrendset.com/demo/easy-responsive-tabs/Index.html. All solutions require decent amount of adjusting the css and other crap.

Comment: Responsive would be nice but more important is the possibility to link directly to a dropdown tab

Comment: Use the Bootstrap tabs they are integrated into BS3. GetBootstrap.com has the instructions

Comment: Basically, if you've seen the Bootstrap tabs with that function, then you're okay, if there is not an example of it on their site, you should skip it. http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/ have the most features.