# fixed navbar covers up anchors when using sidebar affixed and scrollspy in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use Twitter bootstrap's sidenav, as seen in their ["Getting started"](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn) guide on the left hand side.  I have managed to use their page as an example and build my own sidebar.  However, I noticed that on both my sidebar and theirs, the links to anchors do not work properly.  It scrolls to the point below the anchor by maybe 40 pixels.  This cuts off the top of the header.

For example, go to the "Getting started" guide and on the side navbar, click on "Additional downloads."  It scrolls past the header and cuts off the top part of the section.

Does this happen for anyone else?  It happens in my IE, Chrome, and Firefox running on a Windows machine.  I can't seem to find the cause of this to fix my own side navbar.

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11854#issuecomment-30453949 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476045/page-scrolls-to-top-also-fixed-navbar-when-external-link-opens-tab/20477243#20477243

Comment: It happens to everyone, the comment above shows the thread on BS3 and the answer is in the other SO link